# lotus notesでhtmlメールを受信すると表幅指定が無視される

Tags: html

社内のメールクライアントでは、ノーツを利用しています。

現在SmtpClientを利用してhtmlメールを送信するプログラムを作成しています。

そこでtableのwidth指定しているにも関わらず効かない（ウィンドウサイズに合わせて可変になる）という現象が発生しています。

※gmailで確認すると正しく幅固定されていました。ウィンドウサイズに関わらずスクロールが出てきて表幅が固定されています。

ノーツを利用されている方がいましたら対策を教えて頂けないでしょうか。

よろしくお願いします。